# how to pass array from one callback to another or in different block ,

Tags: node.js

1. I have to pass all the users id in 2nd if(type==="1")
2. Here is my code What I am doing wrong :

   ```
   var list = [];

   if (type === "0") {
     console.log("# send to users #");
     var query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = " + id;
     connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         throw err;
       } else {
         if (rows.length > 0) {
           for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
             list.push(rows[i].user_id);
           }
         }
       }
     });
   }
   if (type === "1") {
     console.log(list); //empty
      console.log("# send to group users #");
     var query = "SELECT *FROM group_users WHERE group_id = " + id;
     connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         throw err;
       } else {
         if (rows.length > 0) {
           for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            if(list.user_id !== rows[i].group_user_id){
                  console.log(rows[i].group_user_id); // need to display only those user who is not in the users table
            }
           }
         }
       }
     }); 
   }
   ```

my purpose is to send update contact message only to distinct user, 
since the user may be connected in group so, i want to only distinct user.

Comment: explain more ... put relevant code with `require` statements

Comment: ok, i have updated my query,

Answer (score 0):

It's no clear what you are trying to do, but there are a few things you are doing wrong. First, the list will always be empty when type === '1', and i think thats the problem you are talking about.
Second, list its an array, so this line of code...

```
if(list.user_id !== rows[i].group_user_id)
```

will never work as you want because list as an array doesnt have a key called 'user_id'.
To clarify some concepts:

```
var ex1 = { user_id: '123'};
var ex2 = [123];
console.log(ex1.user_id); //123
console.log(ex2[0]); //123
```

For what you said im guessing you need the list values for the "type === '1'" part, so you should get those values before both if statements, then do with the data what you like, for what i understood, you dont need callbacks to handle this.
Something like this:

```
var list = getListValues();
if(type==='0'){
//do whatever you want
}
if(type==='1'){
//now you have the list values here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for clearing my concept , but I have updated this part 

if(list[0] !== rows[i].group_user_id)
still I didn't get any value. 

see what i am sending  : 

userto_id_list: 
   [ { id: '409', type: '0' },
     { id: '3', type: '0' },
     { id: '618', type: '1' } ];   

In this 618 is a group and group may contains same id(409,3,...) so I need to filter distinct user.

it is iterated using async loop and finding id and type, and then I am checking if(type==='0') and if(type==='1').

Comment: im sorry, im dont understant what you want, i need to see the full code.